# STM32 HAL CAN does not update value and crashes when setting ExtId

Tags: stm32, can, debugging, variable

I'm running my first CAN test program using STM32CubeMX, STM32F103C8T6 and Eclipse.

I used default CAN settings in STM32CubeMX (also tried loopback but the results are equal).

What I see (see pic below) is two things I do not understand;

- In the picture below, you can see I exceeded the line with hcan.pTxMsg->StdId = 0x321 (left red oval), but the current value shows 536891392 (right red oval).
- When I execute the next line (green): hcan.pTxMsg->ExtId = 0x01, I end up in a hard fault interrupt:

  /**

  - @brief This function handles Hard fault interrupt.
    */
    void HardFault_Handler(void)
    {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN HardFault_IRQn 0 */

    /* USER CODE END HardFault_IRQn 0 */
    while (1)
    {
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN HardFault_IRQn 1 */

    /* USER CODE END HardFault_IRQn 1 */
    }

Why is the value not updated and why do I get a hardware fault (the pointer hcan.pTxMsg is not NULL since it even displays the field StdId (it even can display ExtId which has value 134222077 (not shown in pic below)?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Just a wild guess, but did you set hcan to a valid instance (CAN1 or whatever it is called in ST)? Similar the the message pointers. If they are pointing at garbage, something like this might happen.

Comment: @Lundin ... you pointed me in the right direction. For my future reference and others, I added it as answer. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default STM32CubeMx create the initialization code for 'can' (if selected). This code can be found in MX_CAN_Init and is called by main.

However, it does not assign/initialize the pRxMsg and pTxMsg.

The pTxMsg should be defined as:

```
CanTxMsgTypeDef txMessage;
hcan.pTxMsg = &txMessage;
```

and the pRxMsg as:

```
CanRxMsgTypeDef rxMessage;
hcan.pRxMsg = &rxMessage;
```